# not able to enable button using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have 2 fields username and password and login button .Here if i click on username field,its showing number no of users .then if i click on user and password that login button has to enable.but it is not enabling.its enable,if i write both  username and password ,then login button is enabiling,Can u please suggest Me?

```
$("#Username").keyup(function() {
    var len = $('#Username').val().length;
    if (len > 30 || len == 0) {
        $('#Username').css('background', 'rgb(255, 214, 190)');
        blsp();
        if (len != 0) {
            $('#nameal').css('color', 'rgb(255, 57, 19)').text('ID: Too long').fadeIn()
        } else {

        }
        flg.Username = 1
    } else {
        $('#Username').css('background', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)');
        flg.Username = 0;
        tcheck()
    }
});

function tcheck() {
    if (flg.Username == 0 && flg.Password == 0) {
        $('#signupb').css('opacity', '1').css('cursor', 'pointer');
        document.getElementById('signupb').disabled = false;
        // document.getElementById('signupb').enabled = false;
    } else {
        blsp();
    }
}


<input disabled="true" id="signupb" style="opacity: 0.2; cursor: default;" class="signin_btn" name=""   type="submit" value="Login"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [`removeProp`](https://api.jquery.com/removeProp/) jQuery method instead:

```
$( '#signupb' ).removeProp( 'disabled' );
```

Or [`removeAttr`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$( '#signupb' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );
```

Comment: so u mean to say i have to remove to document.getElementById('signupb').disabled = false; and add $( '#signupb' ).removeProp( 'disabled' ); IS it?

Comment: @AbhishekMahapatra yes, or `removeAttr` method. You can choose.

Comment: can i chane in input filed ,what i wrote

Comment: @AbhishekMahapatra I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: In input tag i wrote <input disabled="true"> can i remove or not?

Comment: @AbhishekMahapatra it depend what do you need. `true` make no sense there as input will be always disabled if that attribute is present. So you can have just `<input disabled name="..." ...>` and use `$( '#signupb' ).removeAttr( 'disabled' );` to remove disabled state from input.

Comment: Here one problem is showing like,if select users from this user field,button is not enabiling

Answer (score 1):

You can use `prop`:

```
$('#signupb').prop('disabled', false);
```

> Set one or more properties for the set of matched elements.

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/prop

**OR**

You can also use `removeAttr`:

```
$('#signupb').removeAttr('disabled');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the attribute disabled:

```
$('#signupb').removeAttr("disabled");
```